# Simple or not simple Groups

Tags: group-theory

True or False. Every subgroup of a simple group is itself simple.

Our solution:The statement is false.

As a counter example, let $G$ be equal to the group of even permutation of $10$ letters and $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ which is $$H=\{e,(12)(34),(56)(78),(12)(34)(56)(78)\}.$$ $H$ is not simple since $K=\{e,(12)(34)\}$ is also normal in $H$.

Comment: And what is your question? Your solution is fine, and do you ask to provide with more examples?

Comment: A simpler example: Let $G$ be your $G,$ and let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1234),$ which is of order $4.$ Now is a cyclic group of order $4$ simple?

Comment: @awllower $(1234)$ is an odd permutation.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that... Then just multiply that element by another odd permutation, as done in your nice answer. :p

Answer (score 3):

Suppose an element of the group has order which is not a prime, then it generates a cyclic group which is not of prime order.

This can be done in $A_6$ by $(1234)(56)$

Also note that no group of order $p^n$ is simple for $n\gt 1$, so that Sylow's Therorems guarantee a non-simple subgroup whenever the order of the group has a multiple prime factor.

So this happens with the subgroup $\{1, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ in $A_5$